# How to merge a row in one column when there are duplicates in another

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
structure(list(ZSSLX.10456.FastSeqA.BiopsyTumour_LCM_PS14_1105_1F_100PCent.gz = c(40.9612938016794, 
40.9612938016794, 40.9612938016794, 40.9612938016794, 40.9612938016794, 
40.9612938016794, 40.9612938016794, 40.9612938016794), Stop = c(5864876, 
5864876, 5864876, 5864876, 5864876, 5864876, 5864876, 5864876
), MergeCol = c("1:4864876:5864876", "1:4864876:5864876", "1:4864876:5864876", 
"1:4864876:5864876", "1:4864876:5864876", "1:4864876:5864876", 
"1:4864876:5864876", "1:4864876:5864876"), hgnc_symbol = c("MIR4417", 
"MIR4689", "", "", "NPHP4", "", "", ""), chromosome_name = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("ZSSLX.10456.FastSeqA.BiopsyTumour_LCM_PS14_1105_1F_100PCent.gz", 
"Stop", "MergeCol", "hgnc_symbol", "chromosome_name"), row.names = c(130L, 
289L, 432L, 446L, 1681L, 3467L, 3468L, 3469L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to merge the values in hgnc_symbol if there is a duplicate in MergCol. In this example I would end up with

```
structure(list(ZSSLX.10456.FastSeqA.BiopsyTumour_LCM_PS14_1105_1F_100PCent.gz = 40.9612938016794, Stop = 5864876, MergeCol = "1:4864876:5864876", hgnc_symbol = "MIR4417,MIR4689,NPHP4", chromosome_name = 1L), .Names = c("ZSSLX.10456.FastSeqA.BiopsyTumour_LCM_PS14_1105_1F_100PCent.gz", "Stop", "MergeCol", "hgnc_symbol", "chromosome_name"), row.names = 130L, class = "data.frame")
```

Is there a way of collapsing a row in one column based on another column being duplicated?

Comment: There's a typo in `hgnc_symbol` in your output data frame.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected it

Comment: There's still an unclosed quotation in `hgnc_symbol`. When I close it, I get an empty data frame.

Comment: Corrected again. Apologies. That should work I hope.

Comment: So you just want the first row of the data frame for each value of `MergeCol`?

Comment: No. Sorry. I am struggling with dput. I've tried to correct it but just in case, what I want is the values in hgnc_symbol concatenated for all the duplicate values in MergeCol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your trying to make a dataframe do everything a list can do, but if you're willing to combine a vector into a character string, you might do it like this:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df,names(df)[-4],summarize,
      hgnc_symbol=paste(unique(hgnc_symbol[hgnc_symbol!=""]),collapse=","))

#   ZSSLX.10456.FastSeqA.BiopsyTumour_LCM_PS14_1105_1F_100PCent.gz    Stop          MergeCol  chromosome_name             hgnc_symbol
# 1                                                       40.96129 5864876 1:4864876:5864876                1 MIR4417, MIR4689, NPHP4
```

Note that this assumes that every time `MergeCol` is duplicated that everything else except `hgnc_symbol` is duplicated, too.  You can apply the same concept to the other columns that are not necessarily duplicated as well.

Comment: Hi. This doesn't work as I intended. It returns a dataframe with the unique hgnc_symbol values whereas I'm looking to have the hgnc_symbol concatenated for all the duplicate values in MergeCol.

Comment: Currently, this produces output that is identical to the output that you asked for (except that the order of the columns is slightly different).  Since all of `MergeCol` are duplicated, it returns one row of data with the three distinct values of `hgnc_symbol` concatenated by a `,`.  How would you like for it to be different?

Comment: Odd. What I'm getting is: structure(list(ZSSLX.10456.FastSeqA.BiopsyTumour_LCM_PS14_1105_1F_100PCent.gz = c(40.9612938016794, 
40.9612938016794, 40.9612938016794, 40.9612938016794), Stop = c(5864876, 
5864876, 5864876, 5864876), MergeCol = c("1:4864876:5864876", 
"1:4864876:5864876", "1:4864876:5864876", "1:4864876:5864876"
), chromosome_name = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), hgnc_symbol = c("MIR4417", 
"MIR4689", "", "NPHP4")), .Names = c("ZSSLX.10456.FastSeqA.BiopsyTumour_LCM_PS14_1105_1F_100PCent.gz", 
"Stop", "MergeCol", "chromosome_name", "hgnc_symbol"), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: All the other columns apart from hgnc_symbol are duplicated

Comment: Maybe there's some difference in one of the other columns that is somehow hidden. Try `ddply(df,.(MergeCol),summarize,hgnc_symbol=paste(unique(hgnc_symbol[hgnc_symbol!=""]),collapse=","))`.  This should produce a dataframe with just `MergeCol` and `hgnc_symbol`.

Comment: Hmm. That seems to give unique values. Don't understand...There don't seem to be duplicates. What does names(df)[-4] do?

Comment: It tells it to summarize based on all the variables but the fourth column (which is `hgnc_symbol`).  I used that instead of listing all the other variables because your first variables name is so long.  If `hgnc_symbol` is not the fourth variable, then it would produce the dataframe that you described in your first comment.

Comment: Oh. Its actually the penultimate column.

Comment: You can use `names(df)[-(ncol(df)-1)]` instead.